# Search XML of SSRS Reports to find custom code

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have an unknown number of reports that use a specific piece of custom code and I would like to be able to identify all reports that call this code.

The code looks like:

```
dim Counter as integer=0
Public function getCounter() as Integer
Counter=Counter+1
return Counter
end function
```

And I can look in the report code to see where this pieces resides:

```
<Code>dim Counter as integer=0
Public function getCounter() as Integer
Counter=Counter+1
return Counter
end function</Code>
```

But with hundreds of reports, I do not wish to go through them individually. Is there a way to search the  ReportServer database to find this information?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` column of the `catalog` table has the .rdl source.  You can search it like this:

```
SELECT  name,Path       
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog 
WHERE CAST(CAST(content AS varbinary(max)) AS varchar(max)) like '%dim Counter as integer%'
```

Comment: Awesome - appreciate the response. That worked for me.